# MFC/GDI CRgn CreateEllipticRgn is two pixels short?

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

If I do `CRgn::CreateEllipticRgn(0, 0, 120, 120);` the result ends up with two pixels short at the right and bottom.  Why is that?   I thought maybe because a Region is within the outline rather than on the outline but in that case it should have been 1 pixel border around the entire circle instead of 2 off at right and bottom.  Any ideas?

TIA!!

Comment: The left and top are included in the bounds, the right and bottom are not. This way, the length (right-left) and height (bottom-top) are more predictable and easier to calculate.  left=0 right=120 is 120 pixels wide. left=1 right=121 is 120 pixels wide. This is how rectangles work in Windows.

Comment: I know for RECT they do that, but since it was x2 and y2, you would expect to include the point.  Testing gdi+, it does include the point (0,0 to 0,2) gives 3 pixels.  My main issue was mixing GDI with GDI+ where things weren't lining up, I move to all GDI+ and now it lines up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a picture to explain the problem:

```
    //RECT
    hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 100, 0));
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
    Rectangle(hdc, 10, 10, 130, 130);
    //Ellipse
    hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    HRGN hTemp = CreateEllipticRgn(10, 10, 130, 130);
    FrameRgn(hdc, hTemp, hBrush, 1, 1);
```

[image]

From [Rectangle function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle), it points out:

> The rectangle that is drawn excludes the bottom and right edges.
>
> If a PS_NULL pen is used, the dimensions of the rectangle are 1 pixel
>   less in height and 1 pixel less in width.

From [CreateEllipticRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createellipticrgn#remarks), it points out:

> A bounding rectangle defines the size, shape, and orientation of the
>   region: **The long sides of the rectangle define the length of the
>   ellipse's major axis; the short sides define the length of the
>   ellipse's minor axis;** and the center of the rectangle defines the
>   intersection of the major and minor axes.

From the test result, the length and width of the ellipse excludes the bottom and right edges.

Comment: Since `FrameRgn()` says it goes on the outside of the region (it's how I read "Handle to the region to be enclosed in a border"), means the actual region area is inside the outline and the x2, and y2 are treated the same as RECT (needing +1).  If one wanted to make the region itself the precise area (x1, y1) (x2, y2) one should use (x1-1), (y1-1) and (x2+2), (y2+2).   Whereas GDI+ x2 and y2 do not need +1.  Thanks!!